# Magento 2 Error 500 when i open an item

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

i have a problem whem i click in an item of my catalogue. My provider send me the following log error and tell me it isn't a server error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter()
>   must be of the type array or null, integer given, called in
>   /home/fzquisho/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php
>   on line 1582 and defined in
>   /home/fzquisho/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:2475

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: check error log first and post response here

Comment: It might be issue with your custom theme or custom module. So I would suggest please disable your custom theme and module and see, you are getting this issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you using porto theme with magento 2.3.3 you need to update latest patch follow this link to see more detail [Check more detail about solution on this  website inclucing patch](https://magento2expert.com/error-after-indexing-after-upgrade-to-magento-2-3-3-porto-theme/)

if using any other theme contact your theme developer